# Move word (part of text) from one table td into another one within the table by mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouse

I'm curious if there is a plugin or so to move the selected word (which is actually within a table cell) from one cell to another one by mouse.

I guess there might be a ready plugin-javascript solution, but I was unable to find it.

The table is not editable. Just simple `<table><tr><td>...` and so on.

jQuery solution is also acceptable.

P.S. There might be several words or nothing in any table cell. You can select only one word in a cell to pull it by mouse to another cell.

Of course I can reinvent the wheel but probably there is a out of box solution, but I'm still unable to find it.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be a table?

Comment: @Moose yes, it is a table. The goal is to update table data, the data is exactly in <table>  by its purpose, and the updates upon data changes would go to the server to update the database.